# how can we check connectivity between two virtual machine in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I have below questions related to Azure.

1. How can we check the latency between two virtual machine on Azure network as ICMP is not allowed there.
   I have an Linux VM and one Windows Server 2016 VM with SQL standard.
2. How can we check the network performance on Azure.Like to check the alloted bandwidth to a VM.

Regards,
Yugdeep

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, we **can't** use ICMP to test the network, we can use [tcping](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) to test it. if we use tcping, we should open port 80.
[image]

Also we can use **third party tools** to test it.

Linux we can use [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php), windows we can use [Ntttcp](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/NTttcp-Version-528-Now-f8b12769).

Here a article talk about how to test it, and have a report about the result, please refer to [it](https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.